# Can't make PictureBox to be visible- C#

Tags: c#, image, forms, picturebox

I'm trying to use PictureBox object in order to display an image, but i get some "errors"  . If i just add the PictureBox attributes (location, image, size, backColor etc... ) i don't see any image

I then read i need to add the PictureBox to the Form Controller.

I added it and yet, still nothing ... is there any priority of the layers (what in the back what in the front ?, how can i change it ?)

here is the attributes set of the PictureBox:

```
imageFile = new PictureBox();
imageFile.Top = 200;
imageFile.Left = 400;
imageFile.Height = 100;// furnitureSize.Height;
imageFile.Width = 100;// furnitureSize.Width;
imageFile.ImageLocation = (Application.StartupPath + "\\ball4.gif");
imageFile.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\lamp3.jpg");
imageFile.Visible = true;
imageFile.BackColor = Color.Black;
imageFile.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
ownerForm.Controls.Add(imageFile);
imageFile.Show();
```

Please help.

Comment: ownerForm.Controls.Add(imageFile);
problem is with this line I guess.

Comment: Are there other controls at that could overlay the PictureBox? What the Size of the Form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as i thought ( the pictureBox wasn't in the front)
adding : `imageFile.BringToFront();` solved the issue

Thank you all.

Comment: Still don't understand why you use `ImageLocation` and `Image` properties together.

Comment: It was a try to fix it... i removed the 'ImageLocation' attribute setter

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... are you sure you meant

```
ownerForm.Controls.Add(imageFile);
```

and not

```
this.Controls.Add(imageFile);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You must define size to your picturebox

```
imageFile.ClientSize = new Size(100, 100);
```

Comment: I'am happy to help you SagiLow